# RDD how to use a Set as a filter to another RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I needed to find the maximum for a RDD using a tuple as a key. 
The original RDD is defined as : 
testRDD as this :

```
TestRDD(3,249345,038.9,1)
TestRDD(3,249345,785.59,2)
TestRDD(3,249345,584.9,3)
TestRDD(3,249345,427.5,4)
TestRDD(3,249345,410.71,5)
```

I needed to find the maximum of the 2nd column based on the tuple (1,3)
I was able to acheive it by doing the following :

```
val agg_rdd = TestRDD.map(d => ((d.col1,d.col3),(d.col2))).groupByKey()
val max_AggRDD = agg_rdd.map{case ((col1,col3),(col2)) => (col1,col3) -> col2.max}
val ids_maxAggRDD = max_AggRDD.collect.toSet
```

Now I need to use the output of ids_maxAggRDD which id defined as a scala.collection.immutable.Set[((String, String), Long)] as a filter to the original testRDD.

I cant seem to be able to use the value to do this .

```
 val Max_RDD = TestRDD.filter(v => ids_maxAggRDD.value.contains(v.col1,v.col3,v.col2)))
```

1. Should I convert the Set of maximum ids to something
2. Is there a better way to achieve what I want to accomplish?

Comment: You don't have `.value` in Scala `Set`. What do you want to get as a result of `ids_maxAggRDD.value`? And what the logic you want to use to compute `Max_RDD`?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by just using contains without the .value. Not sure if this is the best approach